# tensorflow - how to use 16 bit precision float

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, precision

## Question

`float16` can be used in numpy but not in Tensorflow 2.4.1 causing the error.

Is float16 available only when running on an instance with GPU with 16 bit support?

[Mixed precision](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/mixed_precision)

> Today, most models use the float32 dtype, which takes 32 bits of
> memory. However, there are two lower-precision dtypes, float16 and
> bfloat16, each which take 16 bits of memory instead. Modern
> accelerators can run operations faster in the 16-bit dtypes, as they
> have specialized hardware to run 16-bit computations and 16-bit dtypes
> can be read from memory faster.
>
> NVIDIA GPUs can run operations in float16 faster than in float32, and
> TPUs can run operations in bfloat16 faster than float32. Therefore,
> these lower-precision dtypes should be used whenever possible on those
> devices. However, variables and a few computations should still be in
> float32 for numeric reasons so that the model trains to the same
> quality. The Keras mixed precision API allows you to use a mix of
> either float16 or bfloat16 with float32, to get the performance
> benefits from float16/bfloat16 and the numeric stability benefits from
> float32.

Then when testing on CPU, do I need to change the type manually to float32 to make it run? According to [[TF2.0] Change default types globally](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26033), currently there is no option to change the default float precision.

### numpy

```
import numpy as np
np.arange(12, dtype=np.float16).reshape(3,4)
---
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
       [ 8.,  9., 10., 11.]], dtype=float16)
```

### Tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reshape(tf.range(12, dtype=tf.float16), (3,4))
---
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-dbaa1413ee5c> in <module>
      1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 tf.reshape(tf.range(12, dtype=tf.float16), (3,4))

~/conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    200     try:
--> 201       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

~/conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py in range(start, limit, delta, dtype, name)
   1875     delta = cast(delta, inferred_dtype)
   1876 
-> 1877     return gen_math_ops._range(start, limit, delta, name=name)
   1878 
   1879 

~/conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py in _range(start, limit, delta, name)
   7190       return _result
   7191     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
-> 7192       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   7193     except _core._FallbackException:
   7194       pass

~/conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6860   message = e.message + (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
   6861   # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 6862   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
   6863   # pylint: enable=protected-access
   6864 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

NotFoundError: Could not find device for node: {{node Range}} = Range[Tidx=DT_HALF]
All kernels registered for op Range:
  device='CPU'; Tidx in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; Tidx in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; Tidx in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='CPU'; Tidx in [DT_FLOAT]
 [Op:Range]
```

## Update

When first create with float32 then cast to float16 works. Please advise why the error is caused.

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.reshape(tf.range(12, dtype=tf.float32), (3,4))
print(f"a.dtype is {a.dtype}")

tf.cast(a, tf.float16)
---
a.dtype is <dtype: 'float32'>

<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 4), dtype=float16, numpy=
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
       [ 8.,  9., 10., 11.]], dtype=float16)>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float16')
```

You'll that the default everything will be `tf.float16`. For instance:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float16')

dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

dense_layer.build((4,))

dense_layer.weights
```

```
[<tf.Variable 'kernel:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float16, numpy=
 array([[-0.4214],
        [-1.031 ],
        [ 1.041 ],
        [-0.6313]], dtype=float16)>,
 <tf.Variable 'bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float16, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float16)>]
```

But this isn't recommended:

> Note: It is not recommended to set this to float16 for training, as this will likely cause numeric stability issues. Instead, mixed precision, which is using a mix of float16 and float32, can be used by calling tf.keras.mixed_precision.experimental.set_policy('mixed_float16'). See the mixed precision guide for details.

Read the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/set_floatx).